# Does EventKit eventsMatchingPredicate search pickup individual instances from a recurrent event?

Tags: iphone, ios, eventkit

Does EventKit eventsMatchingPredicate search pickup individual instances from a recurrent event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventsMatchingPredicate:` will return all instances of a recurring events.

Comment: Oh dear. So if you want events between day x and y you may really have to go back 1 year earlier and then work the recurrence out yourself to check???

Comment: PS don't suppose there is a library someone has published to translate a recurrent event with it's recurring rule to actual separate event instances between two given dates?

Comment: Hey Greg, my previous answer wasn't correct. Just tried it myself and you'll get all individual instances from a recurring event.

Comment: phew...I hadn't yet tried to confirm but I was getting worried that you'd have to do it manually